# Exit YouTube fullscreen video

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-javascript-api

I'm loading YouTube videos using JS API. I can play, pause and go fullscreen with external controls but I can't exit fullscreen with double click on the video.

Using the code below try this:

1. load the video with button
2. go fullscreen using internal iframe button
3. double click on video (you will exit fullscreen)

Now my problem:

1. load the video with button
2. go fullscreen using external button
3. double click on video (nothing happens unless you press ESC key)

How can I do this? I need to exit fullscreen by double click (besides using ESC key)

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cs8tnvkh/

HTML

```
<button id="btn_load">load video</button>
<button id="btn_play">play</button>
<button id="btn_pause">pause</button>
<button id="btn_fullscreen">fullscreen</button>

<div id="video_player">
  <div id="video"></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
const YOUTUBE_LINK = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/#VIDEO?wmode=transparent&autoplay=1&rel=0&controls=1&enablejsapi=1&html5=1";
const YOUTUBE_VIDEO_ID = "mPyLF7NxZyY";

var player;

function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {

  player = new YT.Player('video', {
    height: '480',
    width: '720',
    events: {
      // call this function when player is ready to use
      'onReady': onPlayerReady
    }
  });
}

function onPlayerReady(event) {

  $("#btn_play").click(function() {
    player.playVideo();
  });

  $("#btn_pause").click(function() {
    player.pauseVideo();
  });

  $("#btn_fullscreen").click(function() {
    var iframe = $('#video')[0];

    var requestFullScreen = iframe.requestFullScreen || iframe.mozRequestFullScreen || iframe.webkitRequestFullScreen;
    if (requestFullScreen) {
      requestFullScreen.bind(video)();
    }
  });


}

var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/player_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);



$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn_load").click(function() {
    var video_src = YOUTUBE_LINK.replace("#VIDEO", YOUTUBE_VIDEO_ID);
    $("#video_player iframe").attr("src", video_src);
  });

});
```

Comment: I just tested your code, and double clicking exits the fullscreen as expected.

Comment: @RafikTighilt Did you go fullscreen using the youtube button or the external button?

Comment: Your external button

Comment: Are you using chrome?

Comment: Yes I am, but I just tested in FF and it doesn't work indeed.